# How to create a regular expression for this /file/2471/download?token=bhfhGi6k

Tags: regex

I want to track my pages in Google analytics using regular expression. I've multiple pages with different token ids and file number. Also, how I can track everything after /file/

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Please show some effort of what you have tried and the results. Also what are some examples of the strings you want to capture? As it is, your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Not too clear on this, it would be good if you could expand on the question.

This RegEx matches your pattern and captures everything after /file/ ($1), along with the file number ($2) and token ($3):

```
/^\/file\/((\d+)\/download\?token=(\w+))/
```

Comment: FYI `[\d\w]` = `\w`.

Comment: There are some PDF files on the website and I want to simply track when someone download a PDF file. I want to track them in Google analytics using regular expression. What is the best and simple regular expression to use as goal's landing page.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, you are absolutely right. I updated the original answer to account for the change.